# Why does the RFC 7617 auth basic standard put pound before converting to base64?

Tags: http, basic-authentication

Why does the RFC 7617 auth basic standard put pound after username:password before converting to base64. Is it reasonable to stick it?

[image]

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't.

You are looking at an example where the password is "123£".

Comment: When I read it again, my thought was short. Ah ha... It is just example for UTF-8..!